# Merging an external .pdf file in my generated pdf (react-pdf)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

So I successfully generated my PDF file using react-pdf library. I built it using `<Document>, <Page>, <View>` and other components from react-pdf .

The thing is, there are some external .pdf files that i have to "append" at the end of my generated file. I didn't find an exact solution online. There is one stipulation and that is that this .pdf shouldn't be converted to an image, it should be selectable just like the generated pdf already is.

Is this achievable using just react-pdf or is there a workaround?

Comment: Thanks for your answers K J, but I really don't see how to implement what you just wrote to achieve my goal. I was mostly curious if anyone has found a way to achieve this (appending a local pdf to the one generated with react-pdf/renderer) with the same library, or possibly some other libraries

Comment: I just got the input that the local PDF being merged into the generated one can indeed be an image. Does this change the possible solution? Or at least make it less complex?

Comment: Damn...thank you for the elaborate explanation. I will see what I can do